# Why does a Ruby program/process spawn more than one thread?

Tags: ruby, virtual-machine, interpreter

As the title says, why does a Ruby program or process spawn more than one thread?

For example, If I ran a simple program such as this one:

```
ruby -e 'while true; end'
```

and then tried to count the number of threads this program is using, by running:

```
ps -o nlwp `echo $(ps aux | pgrep ruby)`
```

I get the output:

> NLWP
>
> 2

which means the process is using two threads.

I'm using CRuby/YARV 2.5.3 on Linux. I also tried this with 2.3.8, and got the same outcome.

**Edit**

With Ruby 2.6.0, it seems it only runs a single thread. However, when I enable the JIT using the `--jit` option, it spawns two threads.

Comment: I am assuming that by "CRuby", you mean YARV, since that is the only one which has a release numbered 2.3.8, 2.5.3, or 2.6.0. (CRuby is not very descriptive, since e.g. MRI, YARV, MRuby, and tinyrb are written in C.) Interestingly, with YARV 2.6.0 on macOS 10.13, I get 2 threads w/o JIT and 3 with. MacOS's `ps` doesn't have the `nlwp` keyword, so I am assuming you use a different OS, maybe that plays a role.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say which Ruby implementation you are using, so we can only guess:

- Some Ruby implementations use a separate thread for I/O.
- Some Ruby implementations have a concurrent garbage collector, i.e. a garbage collector that runs alongside the mutator in a separate thread.
- Some Ruby implementations have a parallel garbage collector, i.e. a garbage collector that uses multiple threads.
- Some Ruby implementations have a concurrent parallel garbage collector, i.e. a garbage collector that runs alongside the mutator in multiple separate threads.
- Some Ruby implementations have a concurrent JIT compiler, i.e. a JIT compiler that runs alongside the interpreter in a separate thread.
- Some Ruby implementations have a parallel JIT compiler, i.e. a JIT compiler that uses multiple threads.
- Some Ruby implementations have a concurrent parallel JIT compiler, i.e. a JIT compiler that runs alongside the interpreter in multiple separate threads.
- Some Ruby implementations implement concurrency using multiple message-passing VMs, i.e. they run one VM instance per CPU core in separate threads, and implement Ruby threads, fibers, etc. by passing them between those VMs.
- Some Ruby implementations implement tracing and statistics using a separate thread.
- Some Ruby implementations may themselves run on top of another runtime, which may do any one of the things mentioned above.

And there's probably a lot of other reasons as well.

For example, YARV 2.6 will use 2 threads (engine and I/O) when running without the JIT and three (plus JIT) when running with the JIT.

Comment: Ruby 2.6, yeah.

Comment: I'm using CRuby 2.5.3. Also tried it on CRuby 2.3.8. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

Among the two that you have counted, one process is the running ruby process indeed. The other is your `grep ruby`.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. If I tried to explicitly count the number of threads my program is using by counting the number of directories under `/proc/PID/task`, I get two directories/threads as well. The other process, the grep process, is not interfering here as far as I know.

Comment: @aonemd: I don't know enough to comment about `/proc/PID/task` (which also wasn't included in the original question...), but as far as `ps` is concerned, this answer is exactly correct. `ps` will return one process for the actual ruby process, and another for the `grep ruby` command.

Comment: … which is what `pgrep` is for.